# Cascading Deletes Do Not Persist to the Database in my Typed Dataset

Tags: data-binding, ado.net, dataset, cascade, strongly-typed-dataset

Typed datasets in ADO.Net are supposed to be able to cascade deletes and updates when a DataRelation is set up between two tables, say a parent and child.  However I have not been able to get this to work.  I should clarify: It works for me in-memory; but it does not persist into the database.

I set up a test project with two tables in my database: Colors and Boxes.  Each has an ID primary key and a name (e.g. "BoxId, BoxName").  Colors is the parent and Boxes, which also has a ColorId field marked with a Foreign Key constraint.  I then set up a Winform with two DataGridViews on it, one for each table.  I dragged the two tables into a new Dataset, and their relationship appeared in the designer.  I edited the relationship to be "Both Foreign Key and Relation," and I set all 3 referential integrity options to "Cascade" (i.e. DeleteRule, UpdateRule, AcceptRejectChanges).  I also created a DeleteCommand for the Boxes table, because for some reason the designer refused to do so.  Finally, I put a button next to each grid for saving, and put an Update() call in the event handler for each (e.g. `this.boxesTableAdapter.Update(this.pOCDataSet.Boxes);`)

When I run the form and SQL Profiler, I see all my data, and I can delete items in the child (Boxes) no problem.  These deletes generate a DELETE in the database, as well. Excelente.

When I do a delete in the top grid (Colors), the row I deleted disappears, and the row(s) in the Boxes grid also disappear (assuming I NOCHECK the FK constraint in the database). This looks great.  However, in the profiler, clearly only the Colors DELETE statement ran.  The Boxes row(s) are orphaned.  You don't see this on the Winform unless your restart the app, at which point the would-be deleted rows in Boxes appear with a red exclamation icon to their left, indicating they are violating the FK constraint.

This is maddening because it sure seems like my only option here is to code the referential integrity stuff myself, a la using a stored proc to perform a Colors delete (inside of which I'd also do the Boxes delete), or ordering ON DELETE CASCADE on the SQL Server, or even putting inline Boxes deletes in the Colors delete statement.  I keep coming back to the fact that the DataRelation object in my model is supposed to handle this for me.  Clearly the BindingSource objects get it, since they're removing the relevant rows from the child grid.  But why isn't the model first performing Deletes against the Boxes table and then the Colors table?

Answer (score 0):

Deleting rows in a dataset will only mark them for deletion in your dataset; you still have to use a table adapter for every table in the DB you want to delete data from.  You can think of the dataset as your version of the database in memory.  Those changes need to be committed to the database in the correct order to prevent FK errors.  In your case you need to run the update statement for the parent table (colors) AFTER all the deletes for the children (boxes) have been committed like so...

```
this.boxesTableAdapter.Update(this.pOCDataSet.Boxes);
this.colorsTableAdapter.Update(this.pOCDataSet.Colors);
```

Hope this helps.